# The probability of reaching a certain amount of money before going bust in a casino game.

Tags: probability

The gambler has 1000 dollars in his pocket. He wants to reach at 1200 and leave. He is going to bet one dollar continuously on a wager which in case he wins, pays 3(including the original bet) to 1. The probability of the wager winning is 12/38 (5,2% house edge).

What is the probability that this gambler will achieve his goal and reach 1200 before going bust.

Comment: I will assume 12/38 is correct. Then $p(i)=\frac{12}{38}p(i+3)+\frac{26}{38}p(i-1)$. Solve characteristic equation of 4th degree, eliminate roots larger than 1 in absolute value and use boundary conditions $p(0)=0, p(1200)=1$ to find $p(1000)$.

Comment: @A.S. It must be correct though? $(\frac{12}{38})2 - \frac{26}{38} = -\frac{2}{38} = - 0.0526315789$ right?

Comment: Gotcha. The placement seemed like it referred to "probability edge", not cumulative edge.

Comment: @A.S. Thanks for the answer. Can I ask why $(i+3)$ ? Our bankroll goes +2 up when won.

Comment: Then it's $i+2$ ;) (and you get a simpler cubic equation). I wasn't attentive and should have inferred correctly simply on your edge description. It just goes to show that the format of winnings you chose is not the most user-friendly.

Comment: @A.S. I wish I really knew that much math haha. Still it is better than nothing for myself. If you post that as an answer I wanna upvote it!

Comment: Note: only ignore the negative root, not roots >1 in absolute value. One of the roots will be 1, so you are left with a quadratic: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%3D12%2F38+x%5E3%2B26%2F38

Comment: @A.S. Isn't it supposed to be between 1 and 0 since it is a probability?

Comment: No. $p(i)=A\cdot 1+Br^i$ where you determine A and B from boundary conditions and $r$ is a positive root not equal to 1

Comment: @A.S. I am sorry not knowing the English equivalents of some terms is getting me confused. Can I ask what is it equal to as a percentage is it can be expressed in such way?

Comment: $$p(i)=\frac {r^i-1}{r^L-1}$$ where $i$ is your starting capital, $L$ is your target capital and $r\approx 1.0546$ - the root I mentioned/linked. In your case, it's a very small number: $2.4\cdot 10^{-5}$

Comment: Note that $r\approx (1-edge)^{-1}$. Yours is incorrect. You need $r=\frac 1 6(\sqrt{87}-3)$ instead of $\frac{1-p}p$

Comment: @A.S. Okay now I am starting to get it. I used the formula: $$\frac{\left (\frac{1-p}{p}  \right ) ^{1000} - 1}{\left (\frac{1-p}{p}  \right ) ^{1200} - 1}= \frac{\left (\frac{0.506788}{0.493212}  \right ) ^{1000} - 1}{\left (\frac{0.506788}{0.493212}  \right ) ^{1200} - 1} \approx .004378132$$ to determine the probability of reaching 1200 after starting with 1000, with probability of winning being 0.493212, earlier with a different question. I think they are pretty much the same formula?

Comment: They are similar in spirit - yes - but $r$ is different in this case. You can use this method to find probability of reaching target for any kind of (discrete) bet you have in mind - but for larger moves, you'll have to solve characteristic equations numerically.

Comment: @A.S. I pretty much understood everything except for one thing. How does the payout odds (2 to 1, 3 to 2 etc.) influence $r$ ? And what does *x^3* from **x=12/38 x^3+26/38** stand for? 

By the way, thanks for patience and replies :) Appreciated big time.

Comment: Suppose you win $w$ with probability $p$ and lose $l$ with probability $q=1-p$. Then the characteristic equation is $$r^l=p\cdot r^{w+l}+(1-p)$$ One of the roots is $1$ and you need to plug another positive root $r$ into the formula for $p(i)$ from my previous comment.

Comment: @A.S. Thank you so so much.

Comment: @A.S. I have turned it into an Excel file for easy use :) Thank you. Can I ask one final thing? I know that after all, it is simply probability, and shows no certainty. Therefore, it is pretty logical to implement it with games of such like Roulette, Craps, Sic Bo, Baccarat etc. However, if given the house edge is certain, can it also be used with a game like Blackjack?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33934/discussion-between-a-s-and-sarpsta).