# probability to reach a spesific point before other

Tags: probability, random-walk

a frog can jump each time forward or backward (one step) with an equal probability of 0.5,
the frog stands in point 0,
what is the probability that the frog will reach to point 100 before point -1?
tried to look at this answer but not sure that it is the same
[The probability of reaching a certain amount of money before going bust in a casino game.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601527/the-probability-of-reaching-a-certain-amount-of-money-before-going-bust-in-a-cas)

Comment: You could develop an absorbing Markov Chain on the state space $S=\{-1,0,1,\ldots,100\}$ with transition probabilities $$P(X_1=100|X_0=100)=P(X_1=-1|X_0=-1)=1$$ $$P(X_1=i+1|X_0=i)=P(X_1=i-1|X_0=i)=1/2 \text{ for } i\in\{0,1,\ldots,99\}$$ You need to compute $P(\text{Absorbed in State 100}|X_0=0)$. I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to do this, but it should work. You may be able to locate some techniques involving Martingale theory to solve this problem. I am going to show you how an approach involving Markov Chains may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_k$ be the probability of the frog's reaching $100$ before $-1$, if it is currently at $k$, where $1\leq k\leq100$.  We have $$p_k=\cases{
0,&$k=-1$\\
1,&$k=100$\\
\frac{p_{k-1}}2+\frac{p_{k+1}}2,&otherwise}$$

It is easily seen that $$p_k=\frac{k+1}{101}$$ is the solution, so the desired probability is $$p_0=\frac1{101}$$

Comment: Minor issues: 1. You forgot to say "starting from $k$" when you defined $p_k$.  (Your definition of $p_k$ does not mention $k$.)  2. The "otherwise" clause has $p_{k-1}$ for both terms; one of them should be $p_{k+1}$.

Comment: @sasquires Corrected.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is closer to [this version](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3306981/215011) of gambler's ruin, where the random walk is symmetric. If you shift each position one unit to the right, then the frog starts at position ("state") $1$ and you want the probability that the frog hits state $101$ before hitting state $0$. This is the $p=\frac12$ version, so the desired probability equals $\frac{1}{101}$, since state $1$ is $\frac1{101}$ of the way between $0$ and $101$.